# Gson JsonSyntaxException when trying to map objects from JSON string

Tags: java, json, gson

I started experimenting with various libraries for JSON - Object mapping.

At the moment i am using Gson 2.8.6 and I have the following JSON:

```
{
   "data":
   [
      {
         "id" : 123,
         "name" : "ABC"
      },
      {  "id" : 234,
         "name" : "BCD" 
      }
   ]
}
```

The following classes will be used for mapping

Data.java

```
public class Data {
    
   private List<Item> data;
    
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {

   private int id;
   private String name;

}
```

I am getting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $: when calling fromJson() method.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Data>>(){}.getType();
List<Data> list = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(list));
```

Using jsonsimple library i was getting "data" as a JsonArray and then mapping objects while looping inside. Now things are more complex than i thought. Any ideas?

Comment: Json seems to be valid. Please provide full stacktrace of your exception. Also, I personally prefer JSON/Jackson (or also known as Faster XML) library to Gson. However, that's a matter of personal preference, Gson is actually based on Jackson if I am not mistaken

Comment: @MichaelGantman No, these two are quite different things.

Comment: Your JSON document fits the object mapping for a single `Data` instance, so why are you using `List<Data>` that requires JSON array `[...]`? `gson.fromJson(json, Data.class)` does the right thing for your JSON document.